# Remove listed values from string including merged with others

Tags: c#, string, list

I' trying to remove specific listed values:

```
var List = new List<string> { "sun", "open", "look", "night", "cat"};
```

from string:

```
string str = "hello, sunday, opening, look, midnight, cat"
```

like this:

```
string[] inputs = str.Split(' ');
StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    if (!List.Contains(input))
    {
        sbResult.AppendFormat("{0} ", input);
    }
}
string result = sbResult.ToString().Trim();
```

but this way it works only for equal words, but does not removes if listed word is merged with other:

```
"hello, sunday, opening, midnight"
```

and desired output must be:

```
"hello, day, ing, mid"
```

I have to note two things here, I want use it for large amount of values about 90000 in List and input string is long about 100 words or even more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impress your professor with a one-line solution!

```
string str = "hello, sunday, opening, look, midnight, cat";
var list = new List<string> { "sun", "open", "look", "night", "cat" };
list.ForEach(a => str = str.Replace(a, ""));
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: `Aggregate` (`Console.WriteLine(list.Aggregate(str, (r, w) => r.Replace(w, "")));`) would look even fancier (on line less) :)... Performance of this is very questionable but should pass as basic assignment or interview question starting point. Also it keeps empty words - so may want to split/join to get exact result.

Comment: @John Wu Hello, yes I test it for 90000 and it works, I think this is a good answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var keywordList = new List<string> { "sun", "open", "look", "night", "cat"};
string str = "hello, sunday, opening, look, midnight, cat";

var strList = str.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim()).ToList();

foreach (var keyword in keywordList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strList.Count; i++)
    {
        strList[i] = strList[i].Replace(keyword, String.Empty);
    }
}

str = strList.Where(i => i != String.Empty).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```